# Share token between different domains

Tags: javascript, html, web, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm looking a way to securely share a token between one webapp with the front-end of a second webapp.

Environment details:

- **webapp.local**: A PHP webapp that stories some data that are restricted to specific users. This webapp is accessible by VPN only.
- **otherwebapp.example**: This is a Zendesk instance, it allows us to create a plugin (HTML + JavaScript) that is loaded on the client-side.

Notes:

- **webapp.local** and **otherwebapp.example** use different domains (they aren't sub-domain).
- **otherwebapp.example** is not able to access the **webapp.local**. But the front-end will be able (the user are connected to the VPN).

I did some research, and found some options:

- [HTTP Coockies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies): the "SameSite" need to be "None" ([reference](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie)), is it a secure option? I did some tests and seems that they need to be on the same sub-domain.
- [JS postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage): It will need to open a popup or a iframe, I did some tests but still trying to make it works.

The question is:
Is there a best practice or another way to share a sensitive data (token) between a webapp and a front-end located on other domain/app?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a fully secure way to do it because you want to handle the share on the client side and that will be always exposed, though you can take a different approach like share a request token via GET param to the second webapp and there call a validation API that validates the origin of the request (should be restricted to the second webapp domain) and also validate the passed token and then return the actual session token.